# Has maven changed ear-element from "defaultjavabundledir" to "defaultlibbundledir", if so when?

Tags: maven-2, maven-ear-plugin

In a POM-file i found a "maven-ear-plugin" configuration that uses "defaultJavaBundleDir", but it seems that "defaultLibBundleDir" is the correct (according to the schema and various documentation).

The Maven POM schema is version 4.0.0.

Is this a remnant from an older version? I couldn't find an explanation for this change, and would like to make sure we are using the correct notation reliably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In a POM-file i found a "maven-ear-plugin" configuration that uses "defaultJavaBundleDir", but it seems that "defaultLibBundleDir" is the correct (according to the schema and various documentation).

Actually, the `configuration` element of a `plugin` can contain **anything**. So `<foo>bar</foo>` is valid (and will just be "ignored" by a given plugin if it's an unknown parameter).

> Is this a remnant from an older version? I couldn't find an explanation for this change, and would like to make sure we are using the correct notation reliably.

This change has been introduced for the resolution of [MEAR-46](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEAR-46) as we can read in the (approximative) comment of the [svn commit: r471886](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox//maven-commits/200611.mbox/%3C20061106213320.E4BF91A9846@eris.apache.org%3E).

> Added `defaultLibDir` as an alias of `defaultJavaBundleDir` which is more understable

If you look closer at the diff, you'll see that [`defaultLibBundleDir`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#defaultLibBundleDir) is the new name of the parameter and that the old `defaultJavaBundleDir` is declared as an alias.

So both work, both do the same thing, but only the "new" one is documented in the parameters list of the `ear` mojo. You can safely change to [`defaultLibBundleDir`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#defaultLibBundleDir) and this will make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The strange thing is that "defaultJavaBundleDir" didnt work for building the EAR-file through hot deployment in Eclipse (i.e. using m2eclipse + WTP). That is, all jar files where put in the root folder of the EAR-file instead of the specified dir. But when I changed to "defaultLibBundleDir" it actually started working. Can this be due to how m2eclipse interprets the POM?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  We had the same problem with m2e + WTP not deploying the EAR correctly, and changing "defaultJavaBundleDir" to "defaultJavaBundleDir" fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I was using "defaultJavaBundleDir" in my EAR pom.xml and the jars were never getting deployed to lib folder. 
Using "defaultLibDir"  fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting is that the Maven Integration for WTP eclipse plugin (m2e-wtp) only supports the documented `defaultLibBundleDir` option, not the older `defaultJavaBundleDir`.

https://github.com/eclipse/m2e.wtp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=defaultLibBundleDir
https://github.com/eclipse/m2e.wtp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=defaultJavaBundleDir

Comment: I wish I had read this and could have saved 2 days worth of research wondering why Eclipse was behaving differently.